# Selenium cannot find Cookie Accept button

Tags: c#, selenium

Does anybody have any ideas why Selenium cannot find the Cookie Accept button defined below.  I have tried a number of methods and wait strategies but nothing seems to work?  When the Cookie banner comes up the main window behind greys out. URL: https://portal.everybody.org.uk/lhweb/identity/login?

HTML

```
<div class="xn-auth-form xn-login-form">

<div id="IJFIX74FEMS85U04VNHN9XD1G6T36PB6" class="xn-component" style=""><xn-cookiebanner-component params="{&quot;newcomponent&quot;:&quot;true&quot;}">
<div data-bind="css: { 'xn-modal': isModal, 'xn-visible': isVisible}" class="xn-modal xn-visible">

    <div class="xn-cookie-banner-header">
        <div class="xn-cookie-banner-name">
            <div class="xn-cookie-banner-title">Cookies Policy</div>
            <div class="xn-name" style="word-break:keep-all">
                <span>  Cookies created and stored for this site are fundamental to its functionality and performance. Cookies are not used for marketing purposes, nor are any personally identifiable cookies stored.</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="xn-buttons">
            <button class="xn-button xn-cta" data-bind="click: confirm"><span data-bind="text: confirmationYes">Accept</span></button>
        </div>

    </div>
</div></xn-cookiebanner-component></div>    
        <form name="form" method="post" action="/lhweb/identity/login?signin=d367e21d0f8af2faf156cb566b51b78a" novalidate="novalidate">
            <input type="hidden" name="idsrv.xsrf" value="GgTgFinGkFku2cMRPEcwMy9qv4fh3dUGJV26u-jv6Os0VF-1gFmP_JNHPRRz_lywbkTZ4XAaUs5atoqRHKu56gAHU_lfv-ZZplq476ZcpfQ" autocomplete="off">
```

C#

```
IWebElement button1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/xn-cookiebanner-component/div/div/div[2]/button"));
IWebElement button2 = driver.FindElement(By.Name("Accept"));
```

Comment: Post the URL to have a look.

Comment: URL is https://portal.everybody.org.uk/lhweb/identity/login?  I have managed to get past this by loading all the elements from the cookie banner, with 'code' ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*"));  and then running .Click() on element 63.  But I can't work out why I can't XPath to that element directly?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below locators:

XPATH:

```
.//*[@class='xn-button xn-cta' and @data-bind='click: confirm']
```

CSS SELECTOR:

```
.xn-cookie-banner-header .xn-button.xn-cta
```